# android.git.kernel.org: Name or service not known

Tags: android, git, repository

I am downloading the AOSP (the CyanogenMod for the nexus 5). However git.kernel.org is not responding. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-10.2
Getting repo ...
   from git://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git
fatal: unable to connect to android.git.kernel.org:
android.git.kernel.org: Name or service not known
```

Comment: android.git.kernel.org has not been the distribution point for aosp for several years, you must be following a quite outdated guide.

Comment: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_hammerhead is what I am following. Looks new. Itried both 11.0 and 10.2

Comment: @FirstZero - actually, you were correct.  Your critic was mistaken, as the CM setup was attempting to fetch generic AOSP as an ingredient.

Comment: @magnus-back you are mistaken in your criticism, the component failing to download was a part of generic AOSP on which the CM build depends.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The CM manifest has no dependency to the Repo tool. That git is downloaded by Repo's launcher script, which is downloaded through HTTP. I think his copy of the script is old and contains the old URL that doesn't work anymore. If you think I'm wrong please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

For downloading android source code I would suggest please go to the blow

**Git : Android Source Code Repository**

---

**1. https://android.googlesource.com/**

or

**2. https://github.com/android**

or if you want to brows code online

**3. http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/**

---

from the first link I have checked out Camera source code this way

**Git Command :**

*git clone https://android.googlesource.com/name*

name = the specific dir which you want to clone, for camera its
name = platform/hardware/qcom/camera

so for Example :

> Ramdhans-MacBook-Pro:Camera ramdhanc$ ***git clone
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/camera***

Android the Camera source code is on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Repo launcher script (which you can locate with `which repo`) is ancient and needs to be updated. Follow the instructions at http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html to obtain a fresh copy.

Note that a new version of the script was released just a few hours ago and the SHA-1 checksums listed on the page as of writing don't include v1.21 which is what you currently get when you download the script.

Comment: -1 You don't get to criticize someone else for posting this link as an answer and then post it youself!

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Sorry, I'm not following. At the point I posted my answer there was no other answer pointing out that the problem was with the Repo launcher script, which I still think is the culprit. The only other answer (now apparently deleted) suggested that the OP should initialize an AOSP workspace, which won't solve his problem.